# Wrong image names?

Tags: iphone, ios, asset-catalog

I'm adding a couple of pictures to my project for a slideshow which runs static in the background. But I have the feeling that I don't name the images accordingly.

I support iOS 6 - iOS 7 therefore (if I knot getting this wrong) I have to create 3 variants for the three different screen sizes I have to deal with.

default.png (iPhone 3Gs)
default@2x.png (iPhone 4 / 4s)

Those two work great but I'm struggling with name for the iPhone 5 (4 inch).

I tried default-568h@2x.png and default@2x-568h.png.

Has anyone found a way to get this working? There are literally no examples/explanation in the docs.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to add images to use in the app? Or are you adding images for the splash screen (i.e. the start up screen)?

Comment: i guess no solutions available till for our own images only way is put condition and load it manually

Comment: Side note : It should not be `default@2x-568h.png`. It should be `default-568h@2x.png`.

Comment: @Vin you got the case wrong. It should be `Default-568@2x.png`

Comment: @Abizern: Yeah. Actually, I found `568` behind `@` and I wrote it. BTW it's `Default-568h@2x.png`, not `Default-568@2x.png`... right ?

Comment: Yep - As I've put in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xcode 5 you can still use the asset-catalog to support iOS 6, you just need to drag the images on to thumbnail locations in the asset catalog, and then it doesn't matter what they are called.

If you are supporting down to iOS6, it even gives you placeholders for iOS6 specific images.

If you aren't using the Asset Catalog be sure to use the correct case for the image names which are:

```
Default-568h@2x.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png
```

The filesystem on the device is case sensitive, while the file system for the simulator is not, so you need to be sure to get the case correct.

Comment: yeah I knew about that but if I add all the pictures I get an error telling me that I have ambiguous content in my asset catalog. I want Xcode to detect the image as an image for the 4 inch screen. Is there a name I can use?

Comment: How about fixing the ambiguous content issue.

Comment: yeah it leads to my unassigned images which have the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Add the file for your splashscreen with the name you like :

```
Default.png
Default@2x.png
Default-568h@2x.png
```

And add the key `Launch image` in your info.plist`.

[image]

But, as suggested by @Abizem, with XCode 5 is easier to use the asset-catalog.